# Adding several children to a SKSpritenode

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to figure out how to create this row of Sprites. My Input Sprite comes from a `Texture` in a `TextureAtlas` and is not assigned to a parent.
Now every time i run the code below the error log says 'Attemped to add a `SKNode` which already has a parent'. This happens after the first Sprite is added in the for loop.

I tried put the row together with an `Array` as well. This works until i want to iterate through the array in my main scene and add the children. The same error log appears.

I think the solution is probably pretty simple though i can't figure it out for some time now.

```
-(SKSpriteNode*)createRowFromSprite:(SKSpriteNode*)SpriteName{

    tempSprite = [SKSpriteNode new];
    SKSpriteNode *row = [SKSpriteNode new];
    int x = 0 ;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        tempSprite = (SKSpriteNode*)SpriteName;
        tempSprite.position = CGPointMake(x,0);
        [row addChild:tempSprite];
        x += 16;
    }

return row;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course you have the error. you passed a sprite into a method and trying to add it more than once (and having a memory leak cause you actually never use this `tempSprite = [SKSpriteNode new];` object). What you should rather do is pass `NSString` with a filename into your method and create new sprite from this file on every loop iteration. It would probably look like this (i'm not really good in SpriteKit, but i hope you get the idea):

```
-(SKSpriteNode*)createRowFromFile:(NSString *)filename{

SKSpriteNode * tempSprite;
SKSpriteNode *row = [SKSpriteNode new];
int x = 0 ;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    tempSprite = [[[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:filename] autorelease];
    tempSprite.position = CGPointMake(x,0);
    [row addChild:tempSprite];
    x += 16;
}

return row;

}
```

and don't forget to release you row object after you've added it. Unless you're using ARC of course

Comment: Thanks you! I figured it out with your explanation.